# How do I pass parameter data to a controller in mvc from an Kendo Grid event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to pass a lot of parameters from my ajax function to my controller.  Initially, I thought I would just do this using a query string but that wasn't giving me the result I wanted, although it worked it was creating an unattractive URL the more data I added.

I thought the better approach would be to take all this data I need to pass, store it as an object and pass that payload into the controller from an ajax function.

The ajax function is triggered from the `.event()` attribute of the `KendoGrid`.

**Kendo Grid**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Models.Car>()
    .Name("requirement-grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Command(command => command
            .Custom("Test").Click("payload"));
        })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetCars", "cars"))))
```

As you can see from the above code, there is a custom command that I've used which triggers a function when you click on it.  The function is `payload` and the code is as follows:

**payload**

```
function payload(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get row data
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    //Create Object
    var obj = {
        Name: dataItem.Name,
        BHP: dataItem.BHP,
        YearOfBuild: dataItem.YearOfBuild            
    }

    //Post via Ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Controller/Method/',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            array: obj
        }),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function (ob, errStr) {
            console.log(ob.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

I access the data of the row that was clicked on and pass it down via the events parameter, from there I create an object and add the data to it.  I then create an ajax call and try to pass it to the controllers.

The controller expects the parameter, the code is as follows but shortened for brevity.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create(object[] obj)
    {           
        return View(obj);   
    }
```

If I use `"POST"` in my ajax function I get an error regarding a anti-forgery token which is missing.  If I use `"GET"` the `obj` parameter is always null.

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Is there a better way to be doing this or is my approach incorrect?

Comment: "I get an error regarding a security token which is missing"...in that case you probably need to include the correct security token. How is your application secured?

Comment: I have updated my question, it is in fact an anti-forgery cookie error.  I know these can be added manually but since I'm not using a form I can't reference it to pass it over.

Answer (score 1):

So this should be a relatively simple change to your code. I am assuming you have an anti-forgery token loaded onto the page and the `action` you are posting to is protected by this. You have two solutions here:

1) Remove the requirement for the token if it isn't needed from the `action` in your `controller`

2) Provide the token as part of the `data package` you are sending back to the server by changing your code from

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Controller/Method/',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            array: obj
        }),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function (ob, errStr) {
            console.log(ob.responseText);
        }
    });
```

to:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/Controller/Method/',
   data: {
     array: JSON.stringify(obj),
     __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
   },

   cache: false,
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function(data) {
     console.log("Success");
   },
   error: function(ob, errStr) {
     console.log(ob.responseText);
   }
 });
```

Notice I have just added a reference to the anti-forgery token as part of the data package for you and this should be read by the controller and allow the command to complete successfully for you if you have the token on the page. if not then just add the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to the view and you should be fine.